# Getting output of Ajax call as [object Object]

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am getting an output of following code [object Object]

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'URL/' +{id},
     type: "GET",
       datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          console.log("Data" + data);                                     
            },
             error: function (xhr) {
              console.log("An error occurred !!");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Then it would seem that `data` isn't a string, it's an object.  What properties of that object are you trying to display, and how do you want to display them?  Consider this an opportunity to familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Go to the debugger and place a breakpoint in the `console.log()` call in your `success` function.  When the debugger pauses, use the debugging tools to observe the runtime value of `data` and see its structure.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return whatever the key is called in your array.
Example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'URL/' +{id},
     type: "GET",
       datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          var objectX = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(objectX['$id'] + "," + objectX['giftB']);                                
            },
             error: function (xhr) {
              console.log("An error occurred !!");
                }
            });
```

We can't see the output of output of your JSON, so we cannot tell you which key is to be used.

Here is the alternate example in case that doesn't work.

```
  console.log(objectX.$id + "," + objectX.giftB);
```

Either should work fine.

Comment: Output of Json:
{
    "$id": "1",
    "giftB": "365644555457",
    "innerB": null,
    "ship": null
}

Comment: I've edited the code. It's not tested but should work, you have to parse the JSON data then pass the new variable using the keys you represented. id would equal 1, giftB would equal 365644555457.

Comment: This should return 1, 365644555457 now.

Answer (score 0):

The default conversion from an object to string is "[object Object]". You are trying to print the string representation of the object.

Comment: Try JSON.stringify(data)